# findViewById not working in a static function inside fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my android application, I have a fragment-fragment1. Inside that fragment, I have a static function 'function1'.I tried to define a buttton inside that static function using,

```
button=(Buton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

But Eclipse throws an error like "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getActivity() from the type Fragment".What am I done wrong? I need this function1 to be static, so that I can call it from another class.I mean, I have to populate the list view from main activity when I select a particular fragment.

Fragment1=>

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment{


public static String feedurl="http://www.abcd.com/en/rssfeeds/1_2_3_5/latest/rss.xml";
static String URL = "";
static final String KEY_HEAD = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_DATE = "pubDate";
public static String headflag="";
int f=0;
static Button button;
    HeadlinesAdapter adapter;
    private TextView mMessageView;
private Button mClearButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    function1();
    populate_listview();

    }


 public static void function1()
 {


     URL="http://www.abcd.com/en/rssfeeds/1_2_3_5/latest/rss.xml";
     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml);
    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_HEAD);
    NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    String MarqueeStr="";

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                    newsList.add(map);


 }
    button=(Buton)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);;// Here it shows error.
    adapter=new Adapter1(getActivity(), newsList);        
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
```

}

And my mainactivity is,

ViewpagerActivity=>

```
public class ViewPagerActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private MessageLoader mLoader;
    private Button mSenderButton, mReceiverButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // We get UI references
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mSenderButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sender_button);
        mReceiverButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.receiver_button);
        // We set pager adapter
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        // We set receiver button listener


        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {


            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) 
            {

            }

            int i=0;
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                   if(position==0){

                   }else if(position==1 && i==0){
                       Fragment1.function1(); // Here Iam calling function1

                       i++;
                   }

            }


            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
            });

        mReceiverButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
        // We set sender button listener
        mSenderButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for ViewPAger that manages background interactions with fragments
     */
    private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

        private Context mContext;
        private String[] frags = {Headlines.class.getName(), Kerala.class.getName()};

        public MyAdapter(FragmentActivity activity) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Fragment frag = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
            if(frag instanceof MessageLoader){
                mLoader = (MessageLoader) frag;
            }
            return frag;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, frags[pos]);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return frags.length;
        }

    }




}
```

Comment: `function1()` appears to be not static!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the signature of `function1()` to be as:

```
public static void function1(Fragment f)
```

and use:

```
button = (Buton) f.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

instead of:

```
button = (Buton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and call the method like this:

```
function1(this);
```

---

However, this method should be instance method rather than static method if there is no purpose for it.

Comment: This answer is correct but you should not encourage such abuse of the static keyword. There are no reasons here for these methods to be static.

Comment: @MarvinLabs You are right, but it seems that the OP needs a static method (see the title), so I give him a solution accordingly.

Comment: I cant call the function from main activity....it shows "The method function1(Fragment) in the type Fragment1 is not applicable for the arguments (new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){})"

Answer (score 3):

Don't use static method as it cannot refer to `Fragment1` instance unless you provide it as input parameter. Besides change the finding of button as below:

```
button = (Buton) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You currently have:

```
static Button button;
```

You should remove the static keyword, and instead write:

```
private Button button;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason here for anything to be static (apart from the constants you put in CAPITALS that should be both declared `static` **and** `final`).

Remove all the `static` keywords from your code and it should work (apart from the CAPITALIZED variables):

```
private Button button;

// ...

public void function1() {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I need to call function1 from another class.So it need to be static no?

Comment: You will need anyway to pass this static function an instance of the fragment. So you might as well call that function on the instance itself. Put some more details in your question about how you want to call that function from somewhere else so we can suggest a refactoring.

Comment: To get current fragment, see http://tamsler.blogspot.fr/2011/11/android-viewpager-and-fragments-part-ii.html

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
button=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);


return v;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You must inflate that particular layout an use that layout to find the id.

**

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, container, false);
button=(Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
return v;
```

**